# Deshabilitar las fechas pasadas en fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Estoy usando la librería FullCalendar y necesito deshabilitar los días que ya pasaron pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Quiero es que al poder entrar en la página no me permita darle click a las fechas que ya pasaron.

Éste es mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkboxeditar').click(function() { // este es el modal? no , esto es un checkbox que habilita/deshabilita campos 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      document.getElementById("razondeeliminacion").checked = false
      $('.titulo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.importancia').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.lugar').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.motivo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fuente').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.hora').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fotografo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.descripcion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.tipo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.periodista').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#btsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

    } else {
      $('.titulo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.importancia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.lugar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.motivo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fuente').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.hora').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fotografo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.descripcion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.tipo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.periodista').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

  var date = new Date();
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  var dd = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      language: 'es',
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
    },
    defaultDate: yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function(start, end) {

      $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.bind('dblclick', function() {
        $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
        $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
        $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
        $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
        /*
         $('[name="title"]').val(event.title);
         $('[name="lugar"]').val(event.lugar);
                        $('[name="motivo"]').val(event.motivo);
                        $('[name="fuente"]').val(event.fuente);
                        $('[name="tipo"]').val(event.tipo);
                        $('[name="hora"]').val(event.hora);
                        $('[name="fotografo"]').val(event.fotografo);
                        $('[name="descripcion"]').val(event.descripcion);
                        $('[name="reportero"]').val(event.reportero);
                        $('[name="etiquetas"]').val(event.etiquetas);
         */
        var form = hanyerck || $('#hanyerck')[0];
        var keys = Object.keys(event);
        while (key = keys.shift()) {
          //console.log(key);
          try {
            var input = form.querySelector('input[name="' + key + '"],select[name="' + key + '"],textarea[name="' + key + '"]');
            console.log(key, event[key], input);
            if (input.nodeName == 'SELECT') {
              var option = input.querySelector('[value="' + event[key] + '"]');
              if (option != null) {
                console.log('selcet====================================');
                //$(input).find('option').removeAttr('selected');
                //$(option).attr('selected','selected').click();
                option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
                // creo que era haci. :) veamos xD
              }
            } else {
              input.value = event[key];
            }
          } catch (e) {}
        }

        //console.log(event);
      });
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

      edit(event);

    },
    eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

      edit(event);

    },
    events: [{
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 1',
        start: '2018-07-01 07:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-01 09:00:00',
        color: '#beeeef',
        lugar: 'Lugar 1',
        motivo: 'Motivo 1',
        fuente: 'Fuente 1',
        tipo: 'Tipo 1',
        hora: '07:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 1',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 1',
        reportero: 'Reportero 1',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta1',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 1',
      },
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 2',
        start: '2018-07-10 09:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-10 11:00:00',
        color: '#ffbbee',
        lugar: 'Lugar 2',
        motivo: 'Motivo 2',
        fuente: 'Fuente 2',
        tipo: 'Tipo 2',
        hora: '09:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 2',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 2',
        reportero: 'Reportero 2',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta2',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 2',
      }
    ]
  });
  //funcion para mover eventos y cambiarlos de fecha
  function edit(event) {
    start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    if (event.end) {
      end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    } else {
      end = start;
    }

    id = event.id;

    Event = [];
    Event[0] = id;
    Event[1] = start;
    Event[2] = end;
    //console.log(event,Event);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'editEventDate.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        Event: Event,
        title: event.title
      },
      success: function(rep) {
        if (rep == 'OK') {
          swal({
            position: 'top-end',
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Se ha modificado el dia del evento de forma exitosa',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          });
        } else {
          swal({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Algo salio mal...',
            html: '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>   04162910634  '
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

function mayus(texto) {
  let val = texto.value
  let result = val.split(' ').map(item => !item.startsWith('#') && item != '' ? '#' + item : item)
  texto.value = result.join(' ')
}
```

```css
.fa-facebook,
.fa-facebook-square {
  color: #3b5998
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #00aced
}

.fa-google-plus,
.fa-google-plus-square {
  color: #dd4b39
}

.fa-youtube,
.fa-youtube-play,
.fa-youtube-square {
  color: #bb0000
}

.fa-tumblr,
.fa-tumblr-square {
  color: #32506d
}

.fa-vine {
  color: #00bf8f
}

.fa-flickr {
  color: #ff0084
}

.fa-vimeo-square {
  color: #aad450
}

.fa-pinterest,
.fa-pinterest-square {
  color: #cb2027
}

.fa-linkedin,
.fa-linkedin-square {
  color: #007bb6
}

.fa-instagram {
  #color: #517fa4;
}

.fa-spotify {
  color: #1ED760;
}

#notification-icon {}

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(http://prensaalcaldiadearismendi.epizy.com/img/imagendefondo.jpg);
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 940px;
}

.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<!-- Page Content -->


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h1>Calendario de actividades</h1>
      <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
  <!--notification -->

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
          <!-- este es para agregar los eventos , mas abajo esta el de editarlos -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo evento
              <div align="center"><span class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-youtube-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-tumblr-square"></span></span>
                <span class="fa fa-3x fa-vimeo-square"></span>
                </span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-pinterest-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></span></div>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Debe ser corto" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Inicial</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Final</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control" id="fotografo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; TODO EL EQUIPO</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso con detalles" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control" id="reportero" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>




          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="hanyerck" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ver/Modificar Evento</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control titulo" placeholder="Titulo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control importancia" id="color" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONAR</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control lugar" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control motivo" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control fuente" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control hora" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control fotografo" id="fotografo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; AMBOS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control tipo" id="tipo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control periodista" id="reportero" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control etiquetas" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="razonmodificacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la modificacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="razonmodificacion" class="form-control razonmodificacion" id="razonmodificacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la modificacion, si aparece algo aqui fue modificado el evento" required disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" id="razondeeliminacion" hidden="true">
              <label for="razondeeliminacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la eliminacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input name="razondeeliminacion" class="form-control razondeeliminacion" id="razondeeliminacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la eliminacion" disabled pattern=".{15,}" required title="explique con mas de 15 letras por que desea la eliminar el evento"></input>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">Seleccione una opcion <br/>
                  <label class="text-danger"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkboxeditar" value="checkbox" onclick="activarcasilla(this)"> Editar Evento</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="text-danger">
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>

          <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
        
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button  id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Guardar</button>
         </div>
       </form>
       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    
    
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     
     <!-- FullCalendar -->
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-alpha/locale/es.js'></script>
```

Comment: Hola Juan Ortiz, tienes que leer cómo crear un [mcve]. Estás compartiendo casi 1.000 líneas de código y mezclando HTML/JS/CSS/PHP para un problema que debería ser sólo HTML/JS y que podría ponerse como ejecutable. Debes poner algo más de tu parte, no simplemente soltar todo el código sin más y decir "quiero esto". Al menos pon un código mínimo (sólo la parte relacionada con FullCalendar) y pon el código generado (a nosotros no nos vale el PHP, es más útil que pongas el HTML generado para que podamos ver el problema). Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: escribi todo el código por solicitud de quienes me ayudan @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: El problema es que la mayor parte del código compartido no nos sirve para nada. Es ruido que en lugar de facilitar la respuesta, la hace más difícil. Lee cómo crear un [mcve] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar el código compartido. Voy a intentar limpiarlo un poco, pero es algo que sería más sencillo si lo hicieses a partir de código generado que tengas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo siento, no soy tan bueno como usted en esto, pense que si colocaba todo el código me prodrian ayudar mejor, me toca leer e investogar bastante (y)

Comment: No es cuestión de ser bueno o no (disculpas si mis comentarios anteriores no sonaron bien). Espero que ahora se pueda ver el problema mejor y alguien te pueda ayudar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es algo parecido a lo que dice [Alfredo Cebrián en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/177958/250) y también parecido a lo que se sugiere en esta [respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15014079/3695983): la idea es cuando se seleccione una fecha, comprobar la fecha con el día de hoy y sólo mostrar el modal si es mayor a hoy (es decir está en el futuro).

He modificado la siguiente parte de tu código (cambiando el formateo de FullCalendar por el de moment.js que tienes en tu código, porque me da menos problemas con las fechas):

```
  select: function(start, end) {

      // leemos las fechas de inicio de evento y hoy
      var check = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

      // si el inicio de evento ocurre hoy o en el futuro mostramos el modal
      if (check >= today) {

          // éste es el código que tenías originalmente en el select
          $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
      }
      // si no, mostramos una alerta de error
      else {
          alert("No se pueden crear eventos en el pasado!");
      }
  },
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando basado en tu código (prueba pulsando en una fecha del pasado y en otra del futuro):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkboxeditar').click(function() { // este es el modal? no , esto es un checkbox que habilita/deshabilita campos 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      document.getElementById("razondeeliminacion").checked = false
      $('.titulo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.importancia').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.lugar').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.motivo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fuente').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.hora').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fotografo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.descripcion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.tipo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.periodista').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#btsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

    } else {
      $('.titulo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.importancia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.lugar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.motivo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fuente').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.hora').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fotografo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.descripcion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.tipo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.periodista').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

  var date = new Date();
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  var dd = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
      language: 'es',
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
    },
    defaultDate: yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function(start, end) {

      // leemos las fechas de inicio de evento y hoy
      var check = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      
      // si el inicio de evento ocurre hoy o en el futuro mostramos el modal
      if (check >= today) {
        $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
      }
      // si no, mostramos una alerta de error
      else {
        alert("No se pueden crear eventos en el pasado!");
      }
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.bind('dblclick', function() {
        $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
        $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
        $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
        $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
        /*
         $('[name="title"]').val(event.title);
         $('[name="lugar"]').val(event.lugar);
                        $('[name="motivo"]').val(event.motivo);
                        $('[name="fuente"]').val(event.fuente);
                        $('[name="tipo"]').val(event.tipo);
                        $('[name="hora"]').val(event.hora);
                        $('[name="fotografo"]').val(event.fotografo);
                        $('[name="descripcion"]').val(event.descripcion);
                        $('[name="reportero"]').val(event.reportero);
                        $('[name="etiquetas"]').val(event.etiquetas);
         */
        var form = hanyerck || $('#hanyerck')[0];
        var keys = Object.keys(event);
        while (key = keys.shift()) {
          //console.log(key);
          try {
            var input = form.querySelector('input[name="' + key + '"],select[name="' + key + '"],textarea[name="' + key + '"]');
            console.log(key, event[key], input);
            if (input.nodeName == 'SELECT') {
              var option = input.querySelector('[value="' + event[key] + '"]');
              if (option != null) {
                console.log('selcet====================================');
                //$(input).find('option').removeAttr('selected');
                //$(option).attr('selected','selected').click();
                option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
                // creo que era haci. :) veamos xD
              }
            } else {
              input.value = event[key];
            }
          } catch (e) {}
        }

        //console.log(event);
      });
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

      edit(event);

    },
    eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

      edit(event);

    },
    events: [{
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 1',
        start: '2018-07-01 07:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-01 09:00:00',
        color: '#beeeef',
        lugar: 'Lugar 1',
        motivo: 'Motivo 1',
        fuente: 'Fuente 1',
        tipo: 'Tipo 1',
        hora: '07:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 1',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 1',
        reportero: 'Reportero 1',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta1',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 1',
      },
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 2',
        start: '2018-07-10 09:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-10 11:00:00',
        color: '#ffbbee',
        lugar: 'Lugar 2',
        motivo: 'Motivo 2',
        fuente: 'Fuente 2',
        tipo: 'Tipo 2',
        hora: '09:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 2',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 2',
        reportero: 'Reportero 2',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta2',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 2',
      }
    ]
  });
  //funcion para mover eventos y cambiarlos de fecha
  function edit(event) {
    start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    if (event.end) {
      end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    } else {
      end = start;
    }

    id = event.id;

    Event = [];
    Event[0] = id;
    Event[1] = start;
    Event[2] = end;
    //console.log(event,Event);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'editEventDate.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        Event: Event,
        title: event.title
      },
      success: function(rep) {
        if (rep == 'OK') {
          swal({
            position: 'top-end',
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Se ha modificado el dia del evento de forma exitosa',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          });
        } else {
          swal({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Algo salio mal...',
            html: '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>   04162910634  '
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

function mayus(texto) {
  let val = texto.value
  let result = val.split(' ').map(item => !item.startsWith('#') && item != '' ? '#' + item : item)
  texto.value = result.join(' ')
}
```

```css
.fa-facebook,
.fa-facebook-square {
  color: #3b5998
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #00aced
}

.fa-google-plus,
.fa-google-plus-square {
  color: #dd4b39
}

.fa-youtube,
.fa-youtube-play,
.fa-youtube-square {
  color: #bb0000
}

.fa-tumblr,
.fa-tumblr-square {
  color: #32506d
}

.fa-vine {
  color: #00bf8f
}

.fa-flickr {
  color: #ff0084
}

.fa-vimeo-square {
  color: #aad450
}

.fa-pinterest,
.fa-pinterest-square {
  color: #cb2027
}

.fa-linkedin,
.fa-linkedin-square {
  color: #007bb6
}

.fa-instagram {
  #color: #517fa4;
}

.fa-spotify {
  color: #1ED760;
}

#notification-icon {}

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(http://prensaalcaldiadearismendi.epizy.com/img/imagendefondo.jpg);
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 940px;
}

.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<!-- Page Content -->


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h1>Calendario de actividades</h1>
      <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
  <!--notification -->

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
          <!-- este es para agregar los eventos , mas abajo esta el de editarlos -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo evento
              <div align="center"><span class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-youtube-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-tumblr-square"></span></span>
                <span class="fa fa-3x fa-vimeo-square"></span>
                </span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-pinterest-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></span></div>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Debe ser corto" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Inicial</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Final</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control" id="fotografo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; TODO EL EQUIPO</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso con detalles" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control" id="reportero" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>




          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="hanyerck" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ver/Modificar Evento</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control titulo" placeholder="Titulo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control importancia" id="color" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONAR</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control lugar" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control motivo" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control fuente" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control hora" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control fotografo" id="fotografo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; AMBOS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control tipo" id="tipo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control periodista" id="reportero" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control etiquetas" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="razonmodificacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la modificacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="razonmodificacion" class="form-control razonmodificacion" id="razonmodificacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la modificacion, si aparece algo aqui fue modificado el evento" required disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" id="razondeeliminacion" hidden="true">
              <label for="razondeeliminacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la eliminacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input name="razondeeliminacion" class="form-control razondeeliminacion" id="razondeeliminacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la eliminacion" disabled pattern=".{15,}" required title="explique con mas de 15 letras por que desea la eliminar el evento"></input>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">Seleccione una opcion <br/>
                  <label class="text-danger"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkboxeditar" value="checkbox" onclick="activarcasilla(this)"> Editar Evento</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="text-danger">
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>

          <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
        
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button  id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Guardar</button>
         </div>
       </form>
       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    
    
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     
     <!-- FullCalendar -->
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-alpha/locale/es.js'></script>
```

Comment: excelente aportación, agregue las lineas que compartes y me funciona correctamente excepto que no permite elegir el día de hoy.

Answer (score 2):

denes agregar lo siguiente en la funcion select:

```
 select: function(start, end) {
    var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if(check < today)
    {
        // Dejar vacio
    }
    else
    {
        $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');        }
  },
```

Comment: no me muestra el modal .

Comment: podrias ver la edicion de la pregunta alfredo?

Comment: Lo que te pone Alfredo es correcto, es básicamente lo mismo que se sugiere en esta otra [respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15014079/3695983) para un problema similar.

Answer (score 1):

Que te parece esta solución [Como bloquear fechas en fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670748/how-to-block-out-dates-in-the-fullcalendar-beyond-a-certain-date/19671070):

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) 
{
   var myDate = new Date();
   //Cuantos días se agregarán desde hoy?
   var diasAdicionales = 15;
   myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + diasAdicionales);
   if (date < myDate) 
   {
      //VERDADERO Hiciste clic en una fecha menor a hoy + diasAdicionales
      alert("No puedes agendar esta fecha!");
   } 
   else 
   {
      //FALSO Hiciste clic en una fecha mayor a la de hoy + diasAdicionales
      alert("Excelente decisión... podemos agendar hoy!!!.");
   }
}
```

Tambien puedes deshabilitar la opción de mostrar el modal en el evento ***select***

```
select: function(start, end) {

  $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  console.log();
  if (Date.parse(end._d) > Date.now())
  {
     $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
  }
  else
  {
    alert('No se puede agendar esta fecha');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres colorear las fechas pasadas:

```
    /*COLOREAR FECHAS PASADAS*/
    .fc-past {
        background-color: #c94b4b;
    }
    /*FIN COLOREAR FECHAS PASADAS*/
```

COLOREAR FECHAS FUTURAS:

```
    /*COLOREAR FECHAS FUTURAS*/ 
    .fc-future{
        background-color: #fcf8e3;
    }
    /*FIN COLOREAR FECHAS FUTURAS*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola esta fue mi solucion para evitar ciertos eventos en el pasado

```js
select: function (start) {  
var date = new Date(start);
var hoy = new Date();
var ayer = new Date(hoy - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    console.log("ayer:" + ayer);
                    console.log("hoy:" + hoy);
                    console.log("start:" + date);

                    if (date > ayer) {
                    //eventos permitidos desde hoy en adelante
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("No es posible agendar eventos en dias pasados");
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el validRange que te permite limitar las acciones del usuario, una vez pongas las fechas limitantes, el usuario no podrá retroceder ni avanzar, esto está en la documentación del full calendar

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, { initialView: 'dayGridMonth', validRange: {start: '2017-05-01',end: '2017-06-01'}});
```

[Valid Range Documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange)